# Windows 2019 Data Centre prompting to install Windows 10 Update

Tags: azure, windows-10, windows-server-2019

One of our Windows 2019 Servers in Azure is prompting to reboot to install windows 10 updates. This seems extremely odd to me. It is an Azure provisioned image.

It is a production server, I don't really want to just reboot and find out. Can anyone give me a hint?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: If you want to see updates that are installed, check the Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient/Operational event log.

Comment: It is obviously just an erroneous notification message.